# How to prevent using onclick when tag created?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a problem. When I try to create a tag through document.createElement, I try to add onclick. When function is active, it starts all onclick in this code

```
const setLiked = (name) => {
console.log(name);
};

const deleteLiked = (name) => {
console.log(name);
};

const getRate = () => {
if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    const root = document.querySelector('#root');
    const tempExc = document.querySelector('#getRate');
    const exc = tempExc.content.querySelector('.exchange');

    for (let key in newRate) {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = newRate[key].Name + ': ';
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = newRate[key].Value;
        p.appendChild(span);
        if (liked.find((el) => el === key)) {
            const like = document.createElement('button');
            like.textContent = ' Избранное';
            like.className = 'liked';
            like.onclick = deleteLiked(key);
            p.appendChild(like);
            exc.prepend(p);
        } else {
            const like = document.createElement('button');
            like.textContent = ' В избранное';
            like.className = 'like';
            like.onclick = setLiked(key);
            p.appendChild(like);
            exc.append(p);
        }
    }

    const clone = document.importNode(tempExc.content, true);
    root.appendChild(clone);
}
};
```

So like.onclick is used, when getRate function starts. How I can prevent it?

Comment: create a working snippet to showcase the problem

Comment: @DCR did you take a look at the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're immediately executing the functions and setting the returned value of the function as the `onclick` value. Your functions don't return anything so the returned value will be `undefined`.

```
like.onclick = undefined;
```

Instead, wrap a function around the callback you're trying to assign.

```
like.onclick = () => deleteLiked(key);
```